# How to call method in a different namespace from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, methods

I am building a desktop application with WPF and want to open a hyperlink in a browser. I can do this by putting a method in the code behind and calling it from the XAML as follows, but how can I call this method from multiple XAML pages?

**XAML**

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.mylink.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">My link text</Hyperlink>
```

**C#**

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could put this into a style in `App.xaml`, e.g.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LaunchLinkStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
        <EventSetter Event="RequestNavigate" Handler="LaunchLinkStyle_RequestNavigate" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

(*The handler then of course would be implemented in App.xaml.cs*)

You then can just reference the style:

```
<Hyperlink Style="{StaticResource LaunchLinkStyle}" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks H.B. Your answer set me on the right path. Here's the complete code:

**In my page:**

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.mylink.com" Style="{StaticResource LaunchLinkStyle}">My Link</Hyperlink>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="LaunchLinkStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
        <EventSetter Event="RequestNavigate"  Handler="LaunchLinkStyle_RequestNavigate"/>
    </Style>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public void LaunchLinkStyle_RequestNavigate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* Function loads URL in separate browser window. */
        Hyperlink link = e.OriginalSource as Hyperlink;
        Process.Start(link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri);
        e.Handled = true; //Set this to true or the hyperlink loads in application and browser windows
    }
```